# Understanding an equality in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let C denote the segment from $z=i$ to $z=1$. I want to show that $|\int_C \dfrac{dz}{z^4}|≤4\sqrt(2)$

my attempt:

I want to use the following theorem:

*Let $C$ denote a contour of length $L$, and suppose a function $f(z)$ is piecewise continuous on $C$. If $M$ is a constant s.t. $|f(z)|≤M$, then $\forall z$ in the interior of $C$ s.t. $f(z)$ is defined, then : $$|\int_C f(z)dz|≤ML$$*

In our case,
$z=i+t(1-i) =t+i(1-t), 0≤t≤1$

therefore we cant quite minimize $|1/z^4|$ but we can minimize $|z^4|$.

$|z^4| = \sqrt{\Big(t^2+(1-t)^2 \Big)^4} = \Big(t^2+(1-t)^2 \Big)^2 = (2t^2-2t+1)^2 = (*)$

$**$ This should be easy to minimize but I can't figure out how to do it $**$

Let's say $|z^4| ≤ N$,  $N$ some constant

Once I've minimized (*), I can use the fact that $|{\Big(\dfrac{z_1}{z_2}\Big)|} = \dfrac{|{z_1}|}{|{z_2}|}$ to get that $|1/z^4| ≤ 1/N = M$

It's also easy to find $L=\sqrt{2}$

The question tells us that $N ≤ 1/4$ but I don't know how to prove that.

Answer (score 2):

$(2t^{2}-2t+1)^{2}=(2(t-1/2)^{2}+1/2)^{2}\geq 1/4$ for $t\in[0,1]$, so $M$ can be taken as $4$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are over-complicating it. $\frac{1}{z^4}$ is a holomorphic function over any half-plane not enclosing the origin, like $\text{Re}(z)+\text{Im}(z)\geq \frac{1}{2}$. The integration path belongs to such region and a formal primitive of $\frac{1}{z^4}$ is $-\frac{1}{3z^3}$, hence by the fundamental theorem of Calculus in its complex version we have
$$ \left|\int_C \frac{dz}{z^4}\right| = \left|\left[-\frac{1}{3z^3}\right]_{i}^{1}\right|=\frac{|i-1|}{3}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}. $$